# Asynchronous Automatic Refresh for my App part, is doing a full reload (synchronous page reload)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ajax, app

I have an announcement web App part, And I defined to have an asynchronous automatic refresh for my App Part each 60 seconds (as shown in the picture).

But I have noted that on Firefox, chrome and Safari the browser will do a full reload and not an Asynchronous reload. While only on IE the reload will be Asynchronous. I am facing a big issue as I am displaying some data inside pop-up dialogs, and when the browser is doing a full reload each 60 seconds the pop-up will be closed automacally..and of course i need the automaic reload to keep the data up-to-date.

[image]